# I have problems to add a value from a variable to a total

Tags: jquery, forms, var

I have this script that calulates the total sum "totalsumma" when I fill a form. It works except from that I can not manage to add value from annonssumma to "totalsumma". I get error message **NaN**. see my attempts at the bottom of the script.

```
    <form method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="do" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="typ_av_kund" value="<?if($_REQUEST['i']){?>intresserad<?}else{?>ny<?}?>">
        <table border="0" width="605" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr valign="top">
                <td width="50%">
                    <div id="left">
                        <h2>Utställare</h2>
                        <b>Företag</b> <font class="ast">*</font><br>
                        <input type="text"  name="ut_foretag" style="width:90%;" value="<?if($_REQUEST['i']){echo $intresse_foretag;}else{echo $_REQUEST['ut_foretag'];}?>">

                        <p>

                        <b>Namn</b> <font class="ast">*</font><br>
                        <input type="text"  name="ut_kontakt" style="width:90%;" value="<?if($_REQUEST['i']){echo $intresse_kontakt;}else{echo $_REQUEST['ut_kontakt'];}?>">

                        <p>

                        <b>E-post</b> <font class="ast">*</font><br>
                        <input type="text"  name="ut_epost" style="width:90%;" value="<?if($_REQUEST['i']){echo $intresse_epost;}else{echo $_REQUEST['ut_epost'];}?>">

                        <p>

                        <b>Telefon</b> <font class="ast">*</font><br>
                        <input type="text"  name="ut_tel" style="width:90%;" value="<?if($_REQUEST['i']){echo $intresse_tel;}else{echo $_REQUEST['ut_tel'];}?>">

                        <p>

<?if($_REQUEST['h']==2){?>
                        <b>Adress</b><br>
                        <input type="text"  name="ut_adress" style="width:90%;" value="<?=$_REQUEST['ut_adress']?>">

                        <p>

                        <b>Postnummer och Ort</b><br>
                        <input type="text"  name="ut_postnr" style="width:22%;" value="<?=$_REQUEST['ut_postnr']?>"><input type="text"  name="ut_stad" style="width:68%;" value="<?=$_REQUEST['ut_stad']?>">

                        <p>

                        <b>Land</b>
                        <input type="text"  name="ut_land" style="width:90%;" value="<?=$_REQUEST['ut_land']?>">

                        <p>

                        <b>Hemsida</b>
                        <input type="text"  name="ut_www" style="width:90%;" value="<?=$_REQUEST['ut_www']?>">

                        <p>

                        <b>Organisationsnummer</b>
                        <input type="text"  name="ut_org" style="width:90%;" value="<?=$_REQUEST['ut_org']?>">

                        <p>
<?}?>       
<?if($_REQUEST['h']==1){?>
                        <b>Önskad storlek på monter (kvm)</b>
                        <input type="text"  name="onskad_m2" style="width:90%;" value="<?=$_REQUEST['onskad_m2']?>">
<?}?>                           
                    </div> 

                </td>
                <td width="50%">

<?if($_REQUEST['h']==2){?>
                <div id="right">
                    <h2><span id="clasp3_1" class="clasp1"><a href="javascript:lunchboxOpen3('1');">Fakturamottagare</a></span> (om annan än utställare)</h2>                       
                    <div id="lunch3_1" class="lunchbox3">

                        <b>Företag</b><br>
                        <input type="text"  name="fa_foretag" style="width:90%;" value="<?=$_REQUEST['fa_foretag']?>">

                        <p>

                        <b>Namn</b><br>
                        <input type="text"  name="fa_kontakt" style="width:90%;" value="<?=$_REQUEST['fa_kontakt']?>">

                        <p>

                        <b>E-post</b><br>
                        <input type="text"  name="fa_epost" style="width:90%;" value="<?=$_REQUEST['fa_epost']?>">

                        <p>

                        <b>Telefon</b><br>
                        <input type="text"  name="fa_tel" style="width:90%;" value="<?=$_REQUEST['fa_tel']?>">

                        <p>

                        <b>Adress</b><br>
                        <input type="text"  name="fa_adress" style="width:90%;" value="<?=$_REQUEST['fa_adress']?>">

                        <p>

                        <b>Postnummer och Ort</b><br>
                        <input type="text"  name="fa_postnr" style="width:22%;" value="<?=$_REQUEST['fa_postnr']?>"><input type="text"  name="fa_stad" style="width:68%;" value="<?=$_REQUEST['fa_stad']?>">

                        <p>

                        <b>Land</b>
                        <input type="text"  name="fa_land" style="width:90%;" value="<?=$_REQUEST['fa_land']?>">

                        <p>

                        <b>Hemsida</b>
                        <input type="text"  name="fa_www" style="width:90%;" value="<?=$_REQUEST['fa_www']?>">

                        <p>

                        <b>Organisationsnummer</b>
                        <input type="text"  name="fa_org" style="width:90%;" value="<?=$_REQUEST['fa_org']?>">

                        <p>

                    </div>                      
                    </div> 
<?}?>   

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <b><?=$produktinfo?></b>
                    <textarea name="produkter" style="width:99%; height:100px;"><?=$_REQUEST['produkter']?></textarea>

                    <p>


                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>


        <table border="0" width="605" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" style="background-color:#FFFFEF;">
    <?if($_REQUEST['h']==2){?>  

            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <h3>M<span id="clasp1_1" class="clasp1"><a href="javascript:lunchboxOpen1('1');" style="color:#990000; text-decoration: none;">o</a></span>nterstorlek och priser</h3>                      
                    <p>                     

                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr valign="top">
                <td width="34%">
                    <div id="lunch1_1" class="lunchbox">
                        <b>Ändra pris/m&sup2;</b><br>
                        <input id="m2pris2" name="m2pris2" type="text" style="width:50px;" value="<?=$m2pris?>" /> 

                        <p>

                        <b>Ändra grundpris</b><br>
                        <input id="grundpris2" name="grundpris2" type="text" style="width:50px;" value="<?=$grundpris?>" />                         
                        </div>


                    <b>Pris/m&sup2;</b><br>
                    <input id="m2pris" name="m2pris" type="text" style="width:50px;" value="<?=$m2pris?>" disabled/> 

                    <p>

                    <b>Grundpris</b><br>
                    <input id="grundpris" name="grundpris" type="text" style="width:50px;" value="<?=$grundpris?>" disabled/>  
                </td>

                <td width="33%">

                    <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background-color:#FFFFEF;">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                 <b>Önskad bredd</b><br>
                                 <input id="bredd" name="bredd" type="text" style="width:40px;" value="<?if($_REQUEST['bredd']){echo $_REQUEST['bredd'];}else{echo "0";}?>" /> meter                            
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                 <b>Önskat djup</b><br>
                                <input id="djup" name="djup" type="text" style="width:40px;" value="<?if($_REQUEST['djup']){echo $_REQUEST['djup'];}else{echo "0";}?>" /> meter                     
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                     <p>

                    <b>Antal m&sup2;</b><br>
                    <input id="m2" name="m2" type="text" style="width:50px;" disabled /> m&sup2; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="eget_talt" value="1" <?if($_REQUEST['eget_talt']){?>checked<?}?> > Eget tält

                </td>



                <td width=33%>
                    <b>Pris för ytan</b><br>
                    <input id="ytpris" name="ytpris" type="text" style="width:75px;" disabled /> kr

                     <p>

                    <b>Totalsumma + moms</b><br>
                    <input id="totalsumma" name="totalsumma" type="text" style="background-color:#ffa; font-weight:bold; width:75px;" disabled  /> kr

                </td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" style="position:relative;">
                    <div id="lunch2_1" class="lunchbox2">
                        <h2>Allmänna villkor</h2>
                        <?=nl2br($villkor)?>
                    </div>

                    <input type="checkbox" name="villkor" value="1" <?if($_REQUEST['villkor']){?>checked<?}?> > Ja! Jag godkänner Sunne Jaktmässas <span id="clasp2_1" class="clasp2"><a href="javascript:lunchboxOpen2('1');" >Allmänna villkor</a></span>

                    <p>                     


                </td>
            </tr>
    <?}?>   

    <?if($hide_submit){}else{ // Om formuläret är korrekt postat så döljer vi ruta för veckodag och skicka-knappen?>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" >       
                    <b>Dagens veckodag</b> (för att slippa spam)<br>
                    <input type="text" name="dag" style="background-color:#ffa; font-weight:bold; width:75px;"  value="<?=$_REQUEST['dag']?>" />    
                </td>
                <td >       
                    <input type="submit" name="b1" value="<?=$knapp?>"> 
                </td>
            </tr>
    <?}?>       
        </table>        

<input type="checkbox" name="ad11" class="add" value="<?=$ad14?>" />
<input type="checkbox" name="ad11" class="add" value="<?=$ad12?>" />
<input type="checkbox" name="ad11" class="add" value="<?=$ad11?>" />
<span id="annonssumma" name="annonssumma">1</span>  

    </form>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        window.onload = function() { calculate() }

        $('#bredd').keyup(calculate);
        $('#djup').keyup(calculate);

        $('#m2pris2').keyup(calculate);
        $('#grundpris2').keyup(calculate);
    });

    var annonssumma = 0;
    $(".add").on("change", function(){ 
        calculate_annonssumma();
    } );


    function calculate_annonssumma(){ 
        $(".add").each(function(){ 
            if($(this).is(":checked")){
                if(!$(this).hasClass("added")){
                    annonssumma += parseInt($(this).val());
                  $(this).addClass("added");
                }   
            } 
            else{
                if($(this).hasClass("added")){
                    annonssumma -= parseInt($(this).val());
                 $(this).removeClass("added");
                }
            }

       } ) ; 
       $("#annonssumma").text(annonssumma);
    } 

function calculate(e)
{
    var bredd = parseFloat($('#bredd').val().replace(",", "."));
    var djup = parseFloat($('#djup').val().replace(",", "."));
    $('#m2').val(bredd * djup);
    $('#grundpris').val($('#grundpris2').val());
    $('#m2pris').val($('#m2pris2').val());
    $('#ytpris')  .  val(   $('#m2').val()   *  $('#m2pris2').val()  ); 

//  $('#totalsumma')  .  val(   parseFloat($('#ytpris').val() ) + parseFloat($('#grundpris2') .val())   );
    $('#totalsumma')  .  val(   parseFloat($('#ytpris').val() ) + parseFloat($('#grundpris2') .val())   + parseFloat($('#annonssumma') .text()) );


}
</script>

<p>

</p>

<p>


</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's a super bad idea to have two functions whose names differ only the the case of the first letter (`Calculate`/`calculate`), and you're also violating a pretty strong convention that capitalizing the first letter is reserved for constructor functions.

Comment: I changed the funtionname to Calculate_annonssumma() but it did not help.

Comment: I tried parseFloat($('#annonssumma').text()) instead of val() but it not help as well

Comment: Should I post in this box or as a new answer? (It's a lot of rows)

Comment: ok, I can't find m2 without quots but I added the other missing quotes. How ever, that did not help, and my calclulations in the script works except for adding the value of annonssumma to totalsumma

Comment: I cant find any  quotes as " .... " ", but I do have fixed all the missing quotes. I did not really understood what you ment with the <span> part. The value does show up in the span when I click my checkboxes, but I dont get the value in my last row when I try to add it using: $('#totalsumma')  .  val(   parseFloat($('#ytpris').val() ) 
+ parseFloat($('#annonssumma') .val()) ... OR ... 
+ parseFloat($('#annonssumma') .text()) ... OR ... 
+ parseFloat($('#annonssumma') .html()) ...... I have tried to change it to a <div> as well but what ever I do I get the result NoN for totalsumma

Comment: OK, so with a 1 in the span it seems to work. It shows my total sum + the 1 in the span with this: $('#totalsumma')  .  val(   parseFloat($('#ytpris').val() ) + parseFloat($('#grundpris2') .val())   + parseFloat($('#annonssumma') .text()) ); .... but when I click the checkboxes the value in the span changes but not in totalsumma

Comment: I thought you just ment the quotes in the form fields. All updated now. I tried to create a fiddle without all the unneccessery fileds such as name, address etc, but it doesn't work at all. http://jsfiddle.net/Q94Q7/6/

Comment: Nothing happens when I click (I use Google Chrome)

Comment: Yes, that works, :) but if you click the boxes you dont get the totalsumma with the boxes value. You need to add value for width and deep to try

Comment: But all my calculates functions workes just fine. The only thing is that I cant get the value from annonssumma added to totalsumma

Comment: Yes, the span value shows upp right when I click the checkboxes, but the "totalsumma" does not change and I want the sum in the span to be added to totalsumma

Comment: No, nothing happens when I check/uncheck the checkboxes

Comment: I understand that you're tired of me, and I thank you for all the help I have received. I have apparently expressed myself wrong because I have not been able to describe what I want to achieve. :) 
If I first click in the boxes so it will be as you describe, but I have to have a function where I can click in the boxes back and forth where the value in toaltsumma changed, and it does not. 
Anyway. A BIG THANK YOU for your help. Have a great day!

Comment: @user3214817 Have you checked my answer?

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a ; after you initialise annonssumma

change to var annonssumma = 0;

Comment: `;` is not compulsory here.

Comment: Thak you, but that did not help. The calc for annonssumma works, but the problem is that I cant add the value to totalsumma

Answer (score 0):

i believe the error is $("#annonssumma").text(annonssumma); should be changed to

```
$("#annonssumma").val(annonssumma);
```

Comment: That did not help and the Calculate_annonssumma() stopped working whan I changed to val

Answer (score 0):

According to our long discussion, I understand that you should have additional event for checkbox changing. 
I have changed your js script to the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.onload = function() { calculate() }
    $('#bredd').keyup(calculate);
    $('#djup').keyup(calculate);
    $('#m2pris2').keyup(calculate);
    $('#grundpris2').keyup(calculate);
});

var annonssumma = 0;

$('input[type="checkbox"].add').change(function(){
    calculate_annonssumma();
    // You should also call calculate() function to recalculate your totalsumm when checkbox state is changed
    calculate();
});


function calculate_annonssumma(){ 
    $("input[type='checkbox'].add").each(function(){ 
        if($(this).is(":checked")){
            if(!$(this).hasClass("added")){
                annonssumma += parseInt($(this).val());
                $(this).addClass("added");
            }   
        } else{ if($(this).hasClass("added")){
                    annonssumma -= parseInt($(this).val());
                    $(this).removeClass("added");
              }
        }

   }) ; 
   $("#annonssumma").text(annonssumma);
} 

function calculate(e) {
    var bredd = parseFloat($('#bredd').val().replace(",", "."));
    var djup = parseFloat($('#djup').val().replace(",", "."));
    $('#m2').val(bredd * djup);
    $('#grundpris').val($('#grundpris2').val());
    $('#m2pris').val($('#m2pris2').val());
    $('#ytpris').val($('#m2').val() * $('#m2pris2').val()); 

    $('#totalsumma').val(parseFloat($('#ytpris').val()) + parseFloat($('#grundpris2').val()) + parseFloat($('#annonssumma').text()));
}
```

So, You should also call calculate() function to recalculate your totalsumm when checkbox state is changed (in your change event for checkbox)
Hope it will help you to resolve your problem. 
Also, here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pkysylevych/Q94Q7/12/)**